# Multiple macros in a worksheet cancel macro to select and add multiple entries in a list box

Tags: excel, vba

I put together the following macros in a worksheet to allow,

- multiple selections in a list box
- makeshift navigation buttons to navigate back and forth between tabs while hiding the unnecessary tabs from view

The first macro should allow me to select and add multiple entries in a list box. When I add the other macros that first macro stops working. I'm only able to put one selection into the list box.

```vb
' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("table19")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


'<---- Start of Nav Link Cod---->
Private Sub Label1_Click()
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("LIST_locations_LIST").Visible = True
 Sheets("LIST_locations_LIST").Select
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Sheets("LIST_Schedule_contact_LIST").Visible = True
 Sheets("LIST_Schedule_contact_LIST").Select
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Sheets("LIST_Admin_LIST").Visible = True
 Sheets("LIST_Admin_LIST").Select
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Sheets("LIST_System_Owner_LIST").Visible = True
 Sheets("LIST_System_Owner_LIST").Select
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Sheets("LIST_Vendor_contacts_LIST").Visible = True
 Sheets("LIST_Vendor_Contacts_LIST").Select
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Label1")
        .Top = Target.Offset(1).Top
        .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
    End With
     With ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton1")
        .Top = Target.Offset(3).Top
        .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton2")
        .Top = Target.Offset(5).Top
        .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
    End With
      With ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton3")
        .Top = Target.Offset(7).Top
        .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
    End With
      With ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton4")
        .Top = Target.Offset(9).Top
        .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
    End With
      With ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton5")
        .Top = Target.Offset(11).Top
        .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
    End With
End Sub
'<---- End of Nav Link Cod---->
```

Comment: "cancel out the first macro."  Cancel meaning?  tell us what happens, what you expect to happen and any errors.  Secondly  First Macro means what the change event?  be more detailed in your question to get a better response.  You are leaving us to guess some info which is never a good thing.

Comment: the issue I am having is that the first macro stops working when I add the other macros.

Comment: The first macro should allow me to select and add multiple entries in a list box. it works fine, then I add the other macros in that first macro stops working period I'm only able to put one selection into the list box.

Comment: comment out the line `On Error GoTo Exitsub` in the worksheet change event method.   Then run your workbook and come back with the line it is breaking on.

Comment: Your change event is designed to handle a single cell.   If you change >1 cells at once it will fail and exit early

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your code is that both of your macros contain a Worksheet_Change event. When the user makes a change to the worksheet, both of these macros are triggered, but they can't both run at the same time. This can cause unpredictable behavior and errors.

To fix this, you can combine both macros into a single macro, and remove the Worksheet_SelectionChange event. The combined macro would look something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    
    ' Allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("table19")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Newvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value
            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
                Else:
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Navigation buttons
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Label1")
            .Top = Target.Offset(1).Top
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton1")
            .Top = Target.Offset(3).Top
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton2")
            .Top = Target.Offset(5).Top
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton3")
            .Top = Target.Offset(7).Top
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton4")
            .Top = Target.Offset(9).Top
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton5")
            .Top = Target.Offset(11).Top
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
        End With
    End If
    
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This code checks if the user has made a change to the drop-down list, and allows multiple selections without repetition. It also checks if the user has selected cell A1, and updates the position of the navigation buttons accordingly.

Note that this assumes that you have placed the Label and CommandButton shapes in the worksheet, and named them as "Label1", "CommandButton1", "CommandButton2", etc. If you haven't done this yet, you'll need to add these shapes to your worksheet and give them the appropriate names.

Comment: _The issue with your code is that both of your macros contain a Worksheet_Change event_.  No.  OP has a `Worksheet_Change` and a `Worksheet_SelectionChange`